# Error when running executable generated by pyinstaller [pyvisa-py]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, pyvisa

I'm trying to build an executable from a simple python script using pyvisa-py but I'm running into error after I run the executable generated by pyinstaller.

Here what my small python code looks like

```
import pyvisa as visa
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("SCPI test")
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=100, bg='lightsteelblue2', relief='raised')
canvas1.pack()


def test_1():
    rm = visa.ResourceManager("@py")
    res_list = rm.list_resources()
    print('res_list :', res_list)
    len_list = len(res_list)
    print('len_list :', len_list)
    if not len_list:
        print("No equipment found.")
    try:
        inst = rm.open_resource('USB0::0x1AB1::0x0588::DS1K00005888::INSTR')
        print(inst.query("*IDN?"))
    except ValueError:
        print("No device found.")


Launch_prgm = tk.Button(text="Device detect", command=test_1, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(100, 50, window=Launch_prgm)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run this code in Pycharm or by directly running the .py file from a terminal outside Pycharm it is working well. But when I build the executable using pyinstaller I got the following error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyvisa/highlevel.py", line 2833, in get_wrapper_class
  File "importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyvisa_py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyvisa/highlevel.py", line 2838, in get_wrapper_class
  File "importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyvisa-py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
  File "test_ea_psu.py", line 17, in test_1
  File "pyvisa/highlevel.py", line 3015, in __new__
  File "pyvisa/highlevel.py", line 2926, in open_visa_library
  File "pyvisa/highlevel.py", line 2849, in get_wrapper_class
ValueError: Wrapper not found: No package named pyvisa_py
```

Apparently I'm not the only one having problems with pyvisa and pyinstaller. Many people on github had this issue as well.
https://github.com/pyvisa/pyvisa-py/issues/216

I'm using python 3.6 on Zorin OS (an ubuntu like OS).
When I do python3 -m visa info I got the following info showing

```
python3 -m visa info
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/visa.py:23: FutureWarning: The visa module provided by PyVISA is being deprecated. You can replace `import visa` by `import pyvisa as visa` to achieve the same effect.

The reason for the deprecation is the possible conflict with the visa package provided by the https://github.com/visa-sdk/visa-python which can result in hard to debug situations.
  FutureWarning,
Machine Details:
   Platform ID:    Linux-5.4.0-67-generic-x86_64-with-Zorin-15-bionic
   Processor:      x86_64

Python:
   Implementation: CPython
   Executable:     /usr/bin/python3
   Version:        3.6.9
   Compiler:       GCC 8.4.0
   Bits:           64bit
   Build:          Jan 26 2021 15:33:00 (#default)
   Unicode:        UCS4

PyVISA Version: 1.11.3

Backends:
   ivi:
      Version: 1.11.3 (bundled with PyVISA)
      Binary library: Not found
   py:
      Version: 0.5.2
      ASRL INSTR: Available via PySerial (3.5)
      USB INSTR: Available via PyUSB (1.1.1). Backend: libusb1
      USB RAW: Available via PyUSB (1.1.1). Backend: libusb1
      TCPIP INSTR: Available 
      TCPIP SOCKET: Available 
      GPIB INSTR:
         Please install linux-gpib (Linux) or gpib-ctypes (Windows, Linux) to use this resource type. Note that installing gpib-ctypes will give you access to a broader range of funcionality.
         No module named 'gpib'
```

Also I installed pyvisa and pyvisa-py using pycharm package installer builtin function (work the same as pip3)

If I do list pip3 I got

```
Package                   Version
------------------------- ----------------------
altgraph                  0.17
apturl                    0.5.2
asn1crypto                0.24.0
Brlapi                    0.6.6
certifi                   2018.1.18
chardet                   3.0.4
chrome-gnome-shell        0.0.0
colorama                  0.4.4
command-not-found         0.3
configparser              5.0.2
crayons                   0.4.0
cryptography              2.1.4
cupshelpers               1.0
cycler                    0.10.0
dataclasses               0.8
defer                     1.0.6
defusedxml                0.7.1
distro-info               0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1
ea-psu-controller         1.1.0
et-xmlfile                1.0.1
httplib2                  0.9.2
idna                      2.6
importlib-metadata        4.0.0
iso8601                   0.1.14
keyring                   10.6.0
keyrings.alt              3.0
language-selector         0.1
launchpadlib              1.10.6
lazr.restfulclient        0.13.5
lazr.uri                  1.0.3
louis                     3.5.0
lxml                      4.6.2
m3u8                      0.8.0
macaroonbakery            1.1.3
Mako                      1.0.7
MarkupSafe                1.0
matplotlib                2.1.1
netifaces                 0.10.4
numpy                     1.13.3
oauth                     1.0.1
olefile                   0.45.1
openpyxl                  3.0.7
pexpect                   4.2.1
Pillow                    5.1.0
pip                       21.0.1
power                     1.4
protobuf                  3.0.0
psutil                    5.4.2
pycairo                   1.16.2
pycrypto                  2.6.1
pycups                    1.9.73
pygobject                 3.26.1
pyinstaller               4.3
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2021.1
pymacaroons               0.13.0
PyNaCl                    1.1.2
pyparsing                 2.2.0
pyRFC3339                 1.0
pyserial                  3.5
python-apt                1.6.5-ubuntu0.5-zorin1
python-dateutil           2.6.1
python-debian             0.1.32
pytz                      2018.3
pyusb                     1.1.1
PyVISA                    1.11.3
PyVISA-py                 0.5.2
pyxdg                     0.25
PyYAML                    3.12
reportlab                 3.4.0
requests                  2.18.4
requests-unixsocket       0.1.5
SecretStorage             2.3.1
selenium                  3.141.0
setuptools                56.0.0
simplejson                3.13.2
six                       1.11.0
system-service            0.3
typing-extensions         3.7.4.3
ubuntu-drivers-common     0.0.0
ufw                       0.36
urllib3                   1.22
wadllib                   1.3.2
webdriver-manager         3.3.0
wheel                     0.30.0
xkit                      0.0.0
zipp                      3.4.1
zope.interface            4.3.2
zorin-appearance          3.0
zorin-connect             1.0
zorin-exec-guard          1.0
```

I have experience using pyinstaller with other python code I have written in the past but I'm a beginner with pyvisa. I spent my whole last night trying to figure out what was the problem but I coudn't so that's why I'm asking here for help. Sorry if the same question have been posted before I searched everywhere a solution but didn't find any.

Comment: Seems as though the issue is the name of the module. Try using `PyVISA-py` instead.

Comment: So to use PyVISA-py what do I need to do ? Because in the pyvisa-py documentation they only told you to import visa (which is deprecated now) and to use '@py' when calling the ressource manager. Do I have to change anything to my import or what ?

Comment: Not sure, I think its best to post this question at github issues itself and then after getting a solution, update it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can always add missing site-package(s) in your list of hidden imports in your `.spec` file. Specifically for missing '`pyvisa_py`' module you can write following `test.spec` file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['test.py'],
         pathex=['/home/user/test/source'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[('/path/to/python/site-packages/pyvisa_py','pyvisa_py')],
         hiddenimports=['pyvisa_py'],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      [],
      exclude_binaries=True,
      name='test',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           strip=False,
           upx=True,
           upx_exclude=[],
           name='test')
```

Note: you can get your '`/path/to/python/site-packages/`' using command `python -m site`

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was searching for similar issue with another library. What I understood is that in such cases,

1. Make sure that the packages are installed via pip.
2. If it still has a problem, try to copy the entire library folder from *"<python_env_path>/lib/site-packages/"* to the *"dist"* folder created by pyinstaller.
3. In rare case, just see if renaming the import to match the folder name.

Ref: https://github.com/pm4py/pm4py-ws/blob/master/WINDOWS_COMPILING.txt

Note: python_env_path is the path to env folder inside the python installation or the actual python installation folder if you don't have a virtual environment.